# Like Operator is not working in oracle view

Tags: oracle, view

I have created a view in oracle. Now i would like to fetch data from that view. So i have written a SQL Query. But the query is not working for not having a specific condition. But if I give that condition the query executes. But the problem is not occurring if i joined the same number of tables (that were used to create view) instead of using view. In the following I am giving the oracle query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   "920_search_report" 
WHERE  lm_culture = '7aacb509-271d-4aca-e040-e00adea40aae' 
       AND hand_person_info_guid = 'eebd4257-7856-4c6e-b6b8-9b886e89e397' 
       AND ( Lower(handicap_type) LIKE Lower('%DQ871J%') 
              OR Lower(skskodenr) LIKE Lower('%DQ871J%') );
```

The above query executes and returns one record but if I omit or comment the third line then the query does not return any records, but it should return one or two. the query is given below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   "920_search_report" 
WHERE  lm_culture = '7aacb509-271d-4aca-e040-e00adea40aae' 
       --AND HAND_PERSON_INFO_GUID='eebd4257-7856-4c6e-b6b8-9b886e89e397' 
       AND ( Lower(handicap_type) LIKE Lower('%DQ871J%') 
              OR Lower(skskodenr) LIKE Lower('%DQ871J%') );
```

Can anyone help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Please describe the different results you get for each query.  'executes' or 'not executes' is a bit vague

Comment: The first query get one record. The second query should get one or two records but it does not get any records for omitting the third line.

Comment: That is peculiar.  It is highly unlikely to be Oracle behaviour and almost certainly something you've done.  Which probably isn't what you want to hear but those are the lessons of history.

Comment: Omitting a where condition can only increase the number of results, not decrease.

Comment: I notice that the queries refer to `hand_person_info_guid` differently - are you sure you copy-pasted them exactly?